# Using Simpson's Rule in Python

Tags: python-3.7, simpsons-rule

I'm trying to get an array from an f(x) function this way:

```
array=list()

for i in range(x):
    parameter= z+(i*change)
    array=f(parameter)
```

Note that x is an integer, z and change are floats established in my code.

The next thing I want is to use simpson's rule using the simps function in scipy. 
I tried this:

```
Simpsons= integrate.simps(array, dx=change)
```

It says there is an error
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem line is `array=f(param)`. You're assigning `array` to the result of `f`, not appending it. You should do `array.append(f(param))`.